# How do I assign an element in matrix?

Tags: python

I have `mat = [[0]*5]*5` to create a 2-d matrix of all zeros. 
When I do `mat[0][0] = 1`, I want it to be only

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

but when I print mat, I get:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

How do I access an individual element?

Comment: You *are* accessing an individual element, however, your "2-d" matrix isn't a matrix at all, it is a *list*, that contains 5 other lists, which happen to be *equal by identity*. As the duplicate target shows, the solution is to create a list which contains 5 different lists.

Comment: even this does the same thing: mat = [[0 for i in range(5)] for j in range(5)]

Comment: No, it doesn't. I don't know what you are doing, there are several inconsistencies with the example input/output you've provided. But that list-comprehension definitely works.